# What cause the code in the for loop execute two times for each time?

Tags: java

I get this snippets from a guide but the guide doesn't explain why. For my understanding, the for loop will evaluate whether **i** equals to 'S', if not equals to S then execute the code inside the loop and **i++** and read in a new buffer to compare with 'S' again. But each time the code **inside the loop** is executed two time but I not sure why, could anyone explain to me?

Code snippets from guide: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjn9E.png

```
 class Example {
        public static void main(String args[])
            throws java.io.IOException{

            int i;

            System.out.println("Press S to stop.");

            for(i = 0;(char)System.in.read() != 'S';i++)
            {
                //The line below is executed twice
                System.out.println("Pass # " + i);
            }

        }
    }
```

Problem solved! https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1dMk.png

Comment: *the code is executed two time*, are you saying the for loop runs twice, and only twice, every time?

Comment: *"will evaluate whether i equals to S"* - I don't see any code which compares `i` to `'S'`.  Which wouldn't make sense anyway, since `i` is an `int` and `'S'` is a `char`.  It's not clear what you mean by *"the code is executed two time"*, can you elaborate and be specific about the behavior observed while debugging, as well as the behavior you were expecting?

Comment: @notyou typo, I mean the code inside the loop is executed twice each time after evaluated

Comment: Even if this code snippet is valid, it is hard to read and to understand the intention behind it. It is ok to demonstrate how a `for` loop works, but please don't do this in real code. The code would be much clearer if you rename `i` to something like `characterCount` and use a `while` loop instead.

Comment: @siegi Yes yes, I know variable naming should have meaning, I think the guide is just for demonstration purpose. Thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a Java programmer, but I bet your loop block executes twice every time something other than `'S'` is entered. If that's the case, it's possible that `System.in.read()` returns the user's letter first, then immediately a:

- 13 byte (`\n` new line, Enter) **or**
- 10 byte (`\r` carriage return) **or**
- 0 byte (`\0` end of file, end of string).

To debug, use this:

```
int b; // byte number as int, can be converter to char

for(i = 0; (char)(b = (int)System.in.read()) != 'S'; ++i)
{
    System.out.println("DEBUG: byte = " + b.ToString());
    System.out.println("Pass # " + i);
}
```

Sorry if this doesn't compile, I come from C# planet, please correct this code as needed.

Should I be right, you must print only when the character is not `\n` nor `\r` nor `\0` (or, when cast to `int`, not 13 nor 10 nor 0):

```
for(int i = 0 ;;)
{
    int byteNo = System.in.read();
    if(byteNo == 10 || byteNo == 13)
        continue;
    char letter = (char)byteNo;
    if(letter == 's' || letter == 'S')
        break;
    System.out.println("Pass # " + ++i);
}
```

or more concise:

```
for(int i = 0, b ; (b = System.in.read()) != (int)'S' ;)
{
    if(b == 10 || b == 13) continue;
    System.out.println("Pass # " + ++i);
}
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/1NYhEmw.png
This is the output I get, does it looks like what you are saying?

Comment: Exactly. First you get the letter you entered, then a 10 byte (`\r`) which is caused by pressing Enter on your keyboard, which is also a "letter" in computer meaning. To fix this, add this: `if(b == 10 || b == 13) continue;` inside your loop, at the top.

Comment: I solved the problem with your suggestions
https://i.imgur.com/iVyJe0n.png
But I'm still not so understand, I will think about it again! Thanks anyways

Comment: Refers to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533117/pressing-enter-triggers-system-in-read-twice
"For example, if I were to type "a" and press enter, it would print out 97, 13, and 10 to the console."
Is it everytime when we press enter to the console the sequence is in what we type, newline, carriage return?

Comment: Consider a text file with three lines, each having exactly one letter on it: `a`, `b` and `c`. Save it and check the file's size. You should see it to be 7 bytes in length. You could be surprised, given it has only 3 characters. If you opened this file in hex editor, you would see that this file consists of seven bytes: `61 D A 62 D A 63` in hexadecimal, which translate to `97 13 10 98 13 10 99` in decimal (`int`), which translate to letters `a \r \n b \r \n c` (`char`). That's because just as letters are saved as bytes, every Enter (newline) is also saved as bytes, with the exception that it

Comment: takes two bytes to save one newline. Your text editor, when encountered with `97` byte (`int` value), prints `a` to the window, but when it encounters `13`, then `10` bytes, it knows not to print a letter, but to interpret this as new line. **Now**, back to your console example, pressing `a` sends `97` to `System.in.read()` method, but then you press Enter, which sends `13` and `10` to the same method, just as every other letter would. This is why you encounter this behaviour. It's normal, you can't avoid that other that insert a conditional to your code.

Comment: Also, I just spotted a bug in my answer: you should only increment `i` if a valid letter (byte) was intercepted. Editing now.